# CSS top property: How properly set the top property of modals

Tags: css, css-position

I needed to fix a modal which bottom part is not within viewport. I found somewhere in the net ( I couldn't find it now, I am still looking for it) that to be able to fix that you should get the outerHeight of the modal then adjust the top property. Now, I added this in the code:

div_parent.css("top",-div_parent.outerHeight());

This actually fixed my problem. But did you notice the dash? My question is why does negating the innerHeight value of the modal fixed the bug? If there were invisible grid in the browser, how would it be numbered?  Where would the x's and y's 0 (zero) value be found? As of the moment, I'm still looking for an article that discusses this. I will update my post if I found any. In the meantime, hope someone could help me understand this. Thanks!

And please note that the position is set to relative. And if it is worth noting that there is a code that will initially set the value of top. It was wrongly calculated and the fix will execute after all data in the modal has been loaded.